# Gls using Bootstrap return "Error in dimnames(x) <- dn"

Tags: r

I am trying to use  the bootstrap in `rms::Gls` but I am getting an error.  Could you please help.

As example I have these data (for these data there is no need to go with Gls but, for now I just need to make it work)

```
set.seed(1234)
eps <- rnorm(30, 0, 5)
b0 <- 10
b1 <- 3
concentration <- rnorm(30, 10, 5)
colour <- b0 + concentration*b1 + eps
# colour <- colour 

dat <- data.frame(colour, concentration)
mod <- Gls(colour ~ concentration, data =  dat, B= 10)

mod
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :    length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Comment: hmmm i cannot reproduce your error. works for me. I am on R 3.6.1, rms_5.1-4

Comment: Works for you? That's strange. Well, I had to update the rms but still it doesn't work. I have as well R 3.6.1 and rms 5.1.4... any ides what can be wrong?